# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent NodeJs 4

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created a small project. I just added a parameter control, but if I don't send `id` I get this error. Where is problem?

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

```
const Express = require('express');
const BodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = Express();

app.use(BodyParser.json());
app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
        return res.send(200);
    }
    next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.write('Test');
    res.end();
});

app.post("/test", (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body.id) {
        res.send(200).json({code: 400, message: 'error'});
        return;
    }
})

server = app.listen(8000);
```

Comment: when you use res.json(), then by default it will disconnect connection, no need to do res.end().

res.json() and res.end() also a response, so in node you can send response only once.

And Can't set headers after they are sent:  error means you trying to send response more then once

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the `.end()`. According to the docs (https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end):

> Use to quickly end the response without any data. If you need to
>   respond with data, instead use methods such as res.send() and
>   res.json().

So basically, when you call `.json()` it sends the response headers, and then calling `end()` sends them again

Comment: I removed end() but I get same error. res.status(400).json({code: 400, message: 'Error parameter'});